# Is there a way to get the namespace of an Angular controller when using "Controller As" syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given an AngularJS `ngController` directive like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl as herpderp">…</div>
```

is there a way to get the namespace ("herpderp") from *inside* `SomeCtrl`?  For example, when I want to use "herpderp" for registering that particular controller instance with some other part of my app, or track the controller under a clear name where `$scope.$id` wouldn't do.

**Clarification / update:** I know that inside my controller code I can access `$scope.herpderp`—in this particular example.  The problem is that I am writing a controller than might be instantiated a few times in a page, in different parts, under different "names", so the `$scope` property (`herpderp` in the example above) would be different every time.  So, taking my example, I'd like to get the information what "B" is in `ng-controller="A as B"` (`SomeCtrl as herpderp`).

Comment: by namespace, do you mean the angular module?

Comment: I mean I'd like to get the information _"in the $scope, this controller instance is called `herpderp`"_.

Comment: to get the scope data from html is as simple as {{myVar} if you declared it as $scope.myVar

Comment: @Dalorzo: thanks, but that's not what I was asking, sorry for the confusion.  Please see the added clarification in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your controller you want to find out how you created it? e.g. `MyCtrl as A` vs `MyCtrl as B`. If so I think you could do something like this.

```
for (key in $scope) {
    if ($scope[key] === this) {
        //if you created the controller with "MyCtrl as X" then this will log "X"
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the controller as syntax your controller will still be attached to the scope. So you can say `$scope.herpderp.foo` to access something on your controller. From inside your controller you can just use `this.foo` to access the same variable. And from html you would use `herpderp.foo`.

Not sure if that answers what you were asking though.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't.  I've just added a clarification in my original question.